# Angular Modal Service does not gray out background

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following sample at plunkur
[click here to open link](http://plnkr.co/edit/GbeJbwwhwcs7plniPYth?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap']);

try {
app.service('loginModalService', function ($modal, $rootScope) {

    function assignCurrentUser(user) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = user;
        return user;
    }

    return function () {
        var instance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'loginModalTemplate.html',
            controller: 'LoginModalCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'LoginModalCtrl',
            windowClass: 'vertical-center',
            backdrop: true,
            backdrop: 'static',
            sticky: true
        })

        return instance.result.then(assignCurrentUser);
    };

});
} catch (e) {
alert("Error --- " + e.message);
}


//UsersAPI is service to validate on server
app.controller('LoginModalCtrl', function ($scope, loginModalService) {

this.cancel = $scope.$dismiss;
$scope.showModal = function () {
    loginModalService()
         .then(function () {
             alert("OK Selected ");
             //return $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
         })
         .catch(function () {
             console.log("User Cancelled Login hence Navigation Cancelled ");
             //return $state.go('home');
         });
}
this.submit = function (email, password) {
    //  UsersApi.login(email, password).then(function (user) {
    //      $scope.$close(user);
    //  });
    $scope.$close("abc");
};

});
```

I am not able to get the grayed background tried using fade.
If i add fade into the class, the modal does not open

What am i missing ?

Additionally why is not displaying itself in the center of the screen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In [Bootstrap 3.3.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14927/files), the .modal-backdrop CSS properties were modified.  The change resulted in the modal-backdrop having absolute positioning, instead of fixed positioning and no bottom property set.  Instead of using the bottom property, the Bootstrap JS file injects an inline style setting the height of the modal-backdrop to the height of the viewport.  The modal service in **UI-Bootstrap 0.12.0** doesn't inject the height on the modal-backdrop, thus, the backdrop is there, but it has no height and you don't see it.

There are two ways to approach this:

1. You can do as suggested by @sal-niro and use an older version of the Bootstrap CSS, **or**
2. You can simply add the following to your custom styles:

**CSS:**

```
.modal-backdrop {
  bottom:0;
}
```

To answer your second question about **how to center the modal vertically** in the window, you can use a little custom CSS to accomplish this too.  FYI, this approach is based on CSS transform so it is **not supported in IE8** and only supported in IE9 with the -ms- prefix.

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog, .modal.in .modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  width:100%;
}
```

## [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/frWDRbrVdSgsLtGpt2VZ?p=preview)

In the updated demo, I used your code except I modified the template slightly and added it to the template cache.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: @jme11: You're the man! bottom:0; fixed the background overlay not showing problem. Thanks man.